# Obfulscating the app settings files in-cloud but allowing the local app development

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am planning on migrating on-prem stored projects into the **Azure DevOps** to enable seamless CI/DI experience.
The **Azure key vault** will be used to secure the secrets stored in app config files of .Net applications. Therefore, the config files of solutions will NOT contain any sensitive information in them.. all the variables in `json` and `xml` configuration files are replaced in the `pipelines/release` in `azure devops`..

But now comes the question - if all secrets are obfulscated in the code repository from all places - then how do you build and test solutions **locally** in the Visual Studio?

I have came up with several theoretical solutions;

1. Store the whole `appsettings.Development.json` files (or specific secrets from these files) in `Azure Key Vault`. Then make the `VSIX` VS extension, that would be able to connect to the vault and retrieve the settings file (or secret values) for specific solution after the code checkout.

The downside of this approach is that .Net framework (unlike .net core) web applications are using the `Web.Config` files, so I am not able to use the separate `web.development.config` file for the debugging. XML transformation is not applied during the build as far as I remember.. *p.s. I am planning on adding all `appsettings.X.json`, `Web.X.config` to git-ignore.*

2. Create an `MsBuild` post-build task, that would connect to the vault and replace the variables (in the `bin` folder) before application is started.

The downside is that it is not easy to distribute the MbBuild task among other developers in a team (unlike vsix extension).. HOWEVER - it will allow only mess with values in `bin` folder, leaving the code-versioned config files unaffected. This task must be skipped in the `azure devops`, naturally.

Are there any common secure approaches for sharing the development configuration files among developers without exposing them to the cloud? At this point I feel like second option is the way to go so I would like to hear any advises from the experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're able to use `Web.Config` for multi environment with `SlowCheetah` project - https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/. I was using it with success for one my projects.

To the topic - I've considered multiple solutions for your problem:

**Use emulators for local environment**

For various services in Azure, you can use emulators(Storage Account, Cosmos DB, Service Bus), which allow your devs to develop locally without exposing secrets. Downside - it's hard to share environment with other people.

**Use managed development environment**

It's not like it's always a bad idea to store development settings in your repository. If you can ensure no sensitive data is stored in development environment, you can always stick to development secrets stored for ease. You can also implement ephemeral development environments, but this would require either a mechanism for rotating secrets or creating environments with the same secrets all the time.

**Introduce configuration provider**

You don't have to rely on settings loaded from your local file. For all the secrets, you can introduce a configuration provider in your code, which will connect to Key Vault and fetch secrets according to your environment settings. This will be tricky anyway as you have to "identify yourself" somehow in order to be able to connect to Key Vault and read the secrets.

Depending on your needs, I'd go for 1 > 3 > 2.

Comment: This is nice! So you can actually distribute msbuild 
 tasks through the `nuget` packages! something to learn from the `slowcheetah`! I will have to evaluate all options.. thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Azure App Configurations? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview

This way you can separate your code from your secrets and will just need a connection string to connect to the app configs u manage in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Azure Key Vault for both development and production. But creating a separate key vault instance for developers and production. then you just as a developer need one credential to get all the local development config, just as in production you can get the config in the same way.